# Porque mi token no persiste despues de un request?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Estoy creando un api con expressjs y mongodb:

Tengo en mi controlador los siguientes metodos:

```
exports.login = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
  
    // Validate emil & password
    if (!email || !password) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Please provide an email and password', 400));
    }
  
    // Check for user
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');
  
    if (!user) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid credentials', 401));
    }
  
    // Check if password matches
    const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password);
  
    if (!isMatch) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid credentials', 401));
    }

    sendTokenResponse(user, 200, res);

  });
```

Despues de logearme obtengo un token que automaticamente se agrega a los headers de todas mis rutas protegidas por mi middleware:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const asyncHandler = require('./async');
const ErrorResponse = require('../utils/errorResponse');
const User = require('../models/User');

// Protect Routes 
exports.protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let token;
  
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')) {
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
      } else if (req.cookies.token) {
        token = req.cookies.token;
      }
  
    // Make sure token exists
    if (!token) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Not authorized to access this route', 401));
    }
  
    try {
      // Verify token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  
      // Check if decoded has id property
      if (!decoded.id) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid token', 401));
      }
  
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
      if (!req.user) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse('User not found', 404));
      }
  
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid token', 401));
    }
  });
```

Ahora yo tengo tambien el metodo registrar:

```
exports.register = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
        const { email, password, name, lastName } = req.body;
        const user = await User.create({
            email,
            password
        });

        const employee = await Employee.create({
            name,
            lastName,
            user: user._id
        })


        res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          data: {
            user,
            employee
          }
        })
    
});
```

Este metodo es para registrar usuarios. Para poder registrar usuarios nuevos (crear) tiene que haber un usuario admin logeado. Es decir solo usuarios administradores puede crear usuarios y empleados.

Y esta son mis rutas:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const { 
    register,
    getMe
    login

} = require('../controllers/auth');

const { protect } = require('../middleware/auth');
const { authorize } = require('../middleware/auth');

router.post('/register', protect, authorize('admin'),register);
router.get('/me', protect, getMe);


module.exports = router;
```

Por alguna razon solamente puedo crear un usuario. Es decir me logeo con un usuario admin, obtengo un token y automaticamente ese token se setea en los headers de mis rutas protegidas. Despues quiero crear otro usuario nuevo y me tira el error `Invalid token`. Es decir que mi token no esta persistiendo luego de crear un usuario. Como puedo solucionar esto?